# Calculation of intersections between line segments

Tags: java, android, math, intersection

I need help to understand how to calculate intersections. I have read several of the questions here and looked at several examples on other websites, but I'm still confused and don't get it, and I don't like to copy and paste code without understanding how things work.

So far I know that I'm going to compare the points of each line segments like Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Cx, Cy, Dx, Dy. Could someone explain for me what I'm going to calculate, what would the result of the calculating be if there is an intersection?

This is one of the example code I seen. I don't need the intersection point, just to know if the lines intersect or not.

```java
public static Point lineIntersect(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x4, int y4) {
    double denom = (y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1);
    if (denom == 0.0) { // Lines are parallel.
        return null;
    }
    double ua = ((x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3))/denom;
    double ub = ((x2 - x1) * (y1 - y3) - (y2 - y1) * (x1 - x3))/denom;
    if (ua >= 0.0f && ua <= 1.0f && ub >= 0.0f && ub <= 1.0f) {
        // Get the intersection point.
        return new Point((int) (x1 + ua*(x2 - x1)), (int) (y1 + ua*(y2 - y1)));
    }

    return null;
}
```

Do I also need to calculate some median value like in the following code example?

```
For lines through points (x0,y0) and (x1,y1), let xm = (x0+x1)/2, ym = (y0+y1)/2 (median of line segment). 
Then a = (y1-y0) and b = (x0-x1). 
If you evaluate c = a(x-xm)+b(y-ym), c=0 for (x,y) on the line, and the sign(c) tells you which side a point is on
```

Comment: Are your point integer or float?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The first piece of code you show is based on vector cross-product, which has been explained here [How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect) in a great detail.

IMO, an easier way of understanding it is through solving a system of equations. Firstly look at lines generally and then cut segments from them. Below I use notations for given segments `((x1, x2), (y1, y2))` and `((x3, x4), (y3, y4))`.

1. Check if any of the lines is vertical (`x1 == x2` or `x3 == x4`).

   a. If both are vertical and `x1 != x3`, then no intersection.

   b. If both are vertical and `x1 == x3`, check if `(y1, y2)` and `(y3, y4)` overlap.

   c. If only one is vertical (say, first one), then build the equation of the second line (as outlined below), find the point where two lines intersect (by substituting `x1` into the equation of the second line) and check if this point is within both segments (similar to step 5).

   d. If not, proceed.
2. Use the points coordinates to build lines equations in form `y = a*x + b` (like [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html)).

   ```
   a1 = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
   b1 = y1 - a1*x1 
   a2 = (y4-y3)/(x4-x3)
   b2 = y3 - a2*x3
   ```
3. Check if lines are parallel (same slope `a`). If yes, check if they have same intercept `b`. If yes, check if 1D segments `(x1, x2)` and `(x3, x4)` overlap. If yes, your segments do overlap. The case when lines are parallel can be ambiguous. If they overlap, you can consider it as an intersection (it even can be one point if their ends are touching), or not. Note: if you are working with floats it would be a bit trickier, I reckon you would want to ignore this. In case you have only integers checking if `a1 = a2` is equivalent to:

   ```
   if((y2-y1)*(x4-x3) == (x2-x1)*(y4-y3))
   ```
4. If lines are not parallel. The point of intersection is equivalent to a solution of a system of equations representing the two lines. Really, `y = a1*x + b1` and `y = a2*x + b2` intersecting basically means that both of these equations hold. Solve this system by equating the two right sides and it will give you the intersection point. In fact, you need only `x` coordinate of the intersection (draw it and you'll see why):

   ```
   x0 = -(b1-b2)/(a1-a2)
   ```
5. Last step is to check if the intersection point `x0` lies within both segments. That is, `min(x1, x2) < x0 < max(x1, x2)` and `min(x3, x4) < x0 < max(x3, x4)`. If yes, your lines do intersect!

Comment: Hmm, just another example. I have seen that before, but as with all other examples it's just like a foreign language! I guess my skill in math are a little bit limited, but I don't want that stop me from learning.

Comment: I have all my positions stored as points in an arraylist, and I need to pass them to a method that check if there is an intersection. But I don't know how to start? I guess I only need to check if the overlap!?

Comment: A caveat with this - You need to check for the special case of vertical lines at the start of this method.

Comment: @tofarr Thanks for spotting it. Edited answer to fix this.

Comment: Here is a complete Java implementation of this solution: https://github.com/baobabKoodaa/CodeForcesLibrary/blob/ad6972b1ccd87c9100171122692562704c695703/src/baobab/A.java#L767

Answer (score 5):

I really @sashkello's answer and find it to be more intuitive and easier to explain than the vector implementation. Particularly when adding this kind of code to a code base.

I'll caveat that with saying that you can make use of Java's Line2D helper method.

```
Line2D.linesIntersect(double x1, double y1,
                      double x2, double y2,
                      double x3, double y3,
                      double x4, double y4)
```

The only draw back is that it requires you to consider the segments to be intersecting even when they are just touching (on both end points and the line itself).

For example, the below lines are considered intersecting because they share point (1,1).

```
L1 = [(0,0),(1,1)]
L2 = [(1,1),(2,3)]
```

If that is a problem you can add 4 checks to see if the points are equal.

If you have concerns about a point falling on a point within the line, that takes a bit more work and you're maybe better off implementing it yourself so you can do the checks in the algorithm itself.

If none of those edge cases affect you, then `Line2D.linesIntersect`is for you. :)

Comment: Because this does not solve the question. linesIntersect only returns whether they intersect and not the actual intersection point.

Comment: @JorrickSleijster thanks for the response! I did indeed misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void fixData()
{
    slope = (p2.getY() - p1.getY()) / (p2.getX() - p1.getX());
    yInt = p1.getY() - slope * p1.getX();
    xInt = (-yInt) / slope;
}
```

Comment: This code finds the X and Y intercepts, the the intersection points of two line segments.

Answer (score 0):

*I answered the question at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563297/accuracy-of-line-intersection-with-vertical-line/78054140#78054140), but I wanted to copy-paste my own answer here for future visitors.*

I would like to make the accepted answer dead simple. Note that this is C#, so the syntax is similar to Java and should be easily understood.

```
// Setup formulas:

double A(double y2, double y1) => y1-y2;
double B(double x1,double x2) => x2-x1;
double C(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) => x1 * y2 - x2 * y1;

// Gives the Ax+By+C=0 form of the line
(double A, double B, double C) LineEquation(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) => 
(A(y2, y1), B(x1, x2), C(x1, y1, x2, y2));

//The Mobius version of a Cartesian point, called a "homogeneous point"
(double X, double Y, double Z) HomogeneousPointOfIntersection(double A1, double B1, double C1, double A2, double B2, double C2) =>
(B1 * C2 - B2 * C1, A2 * C1 - A1 * C2, A1 * B2 - A2 * B1);
```

Note the formula `HomogeneousPointOfIntersection` returns a triplet which is called `(X,Y,Z)`. To obtain the actual Cartesian (X,Y) point, you have to do a final division of the X,Y,Z components.

BUT! If the Z component is zero, it means the lines are parallel and you should not do the final division as it will be a NaN error. So you want to return/escape early if Z is zero.

Here is the final sample code.

```
// Test that two sloping lines intersect


(double x, double y) p1 = (4, 2);
(double x, double y) p2 = (7, 5);

var line1 = LineEquation(p1.x,p1.y,p2.x,p2.y);

(double x, double y) p3 = (7, 2);
(double x, double y) p4 = (5, 7);

var line2 = LineEquation(p3.x, p3.y, p4.x, p4.y);

// h_p stands for homogeneous point
var h_p = HomogeneousPointOfIntersection(line1.A, line1.B, line1.C,line2.A,line2.B,line2.C);

if(h_p.Z == 0) return; // Return early as the below will be NaN.In this test example, this will be bypassed as we can get a successful final result.

var actualpointX = h_p.X / h_p.Z; // yields the Cartesian X value
var actualpointY = h_p.Y / h_p.Z; // yields the Cartesian Y value
```

Therefore, this code will handle all conditions with the one edge condition of parallel lines. Feel free to test with vertical and horizontal lines and you will see that these conditions will still return a point intersection.