# How to check whether 2 lines segments intersect?

Tags: java, math

How do I check whether 2 line segments,  L1(p1,p2) and L2(p3,p4), intersect with each other? I do not need the intersection point, I just need to know whether they intersect or not. Since my application calculating this a lot, I need to find a fast solution.

Thanks

Comment: are you referrring to geometric lines (which extend infinitely)?

Comment: @ra_htial: we are having a discussion about what you are really asking. please see the discussion under Andreas Wederbrand's answer. If my edit does not reflect your intentions, please re-edit it.

Is your question about Java's java.awt.geom.Line2D (which according to the docs "represents a line segment in (x,y) coordinate space") or geometrical lines extending into infinity?

Comment: @ra_htial: could you accept an answer or bring something to the discussion on what you are asking?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To test whether two line segments intersect, you can use Java's 2D API, specifically the methods of [Line2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#linesIntersect%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29).

```
Line2D line1 = new Line2D.Float(100, 100, 200, 200);
Line2D line2 = new Line2D.Float(150, 150, 150, 200);
boolean result = line2.intersectsLine(line1);
System.out.println(result); // => true

// Also check out linesIntersect() if you do not need to construct the line objects
// It will probably be faster due to putting less pressure on the garbage collector
// if running it in a loop
System.out.println(Line2D.linesIntersect(100,100,200,200,150,150,150,200));
```

If you are interested in finding out how the code works, in order to see if you can make it faster in your specific domain, you can check out [the code for OpenJDK implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/awt/geom/Line2D.java#Line2D.linesIntersect%28double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double%29).
But remember, always profile before you optimize; it is probably plenty fast enough as it is.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you are asking. What is after the intersection point?

Comment: I assume he means he also wanted to know where the segments intersected. Btw, is there a way I can exclude the endpoints of the lines, st. `(0,0,1,1)` and `(1,1,2,2)` don't intersect?

Comment: @AlessioMTX That is another question. I would start by trying to read the API methods ...

Comment: I didn't find in Line2D and since I didn't know this API, I took a look, but I found no solution, so asked here, maybe I missed.

Comment: @AlessioMTX First hit on google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314069/calculation-of-intersections-between-line-segments

Comment: What if I want to find out if a line segment cuts infinite line? For instance I have line y = x and a point (2,3) and want to find out whether they intersect or not. Line y = x is not defined with two points, instead, it's defined with a formula

Comment: That's another question worthy of a separate post, but you can probably make it work by converting the line into a segment using the max and min values of Long or something like that.

Answer (score 9):

I would simply use the method that does it for you, or look at its source code if you want to reimplement it: [Line2D.linesIntersect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#linesIntersect%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29)

Comment: the same goes here, linesIntersect checks the lines not the segments. And there are a lot of cases where lines intersect but not the segments

Comment: The javadoc says: Tests if the line **segment** from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) intersects the line **segment** from (x3,y3) to (x4,y4) (emphasis mine).

Comment: holy mother of potato :) my bad, one up vote is going for you guys